# Images displayed in Visual Studio Development Server but not IIS7

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, image, visual-studio-2012, iis-7

I am having some problems getting images to work when publishing my MVC 5 project to IIS 7. I have a body style like below that seems to be failing by displaying a white background instead of the image (it skips the grey altogether)

```
body {
background-color: grey;
background: transparent url("Images/Background.png") no-repeat center center fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
height: 100%;
}
```

Ive brought up chrome development tools and looked at the actual link to the image and manually added a "/" then removed it, and the image displayed fine but, upon refresh fails. I get no errors in the console except the 404 errors defined below.

I've also tried the following versions (some of which were more obvious failures than others)

- Images/Background.png (no error)
- /Images/Background.png (404 error)
- ~/Images/Background.png (404 error)
- ~Images/Background.png(404 error)

the latter 3 throw errors as such:

```
- http://10.96.90.65/Images/Background.png 404 (Not Found)
 - http://10.96.90.65/SITE/Content/~/Images/Background.png 404 (Not Found)
 - http://10.96.90.65/SITE/Content/~Images/Background.png 404 (Not Found)
```

My applicable virtual file structure looks like

- /Content
- /Content/Images/
- /Content/Themes/
- /Content/*.css
- /Images/

I am using Visual Studio 2012 and IIS 7
Edit: The image is loading in Internet Explorer but not Chrome

Comment: It "skips the grey altogether" because you set it to grey, then in the following line set it to transparent.

Comment: Oh. Duh. Good catch. But that is more of a secondary issue.

Comment: Yeah, I figured.  Just thought I'd mention it since I noticed it.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [html base tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base)?

I previously had an issue where I couldn't get to the image on IIS but could when running locally.  I also think there was an IIS setting that could be changed, but that wasn't a possibility for me at the time so I never researched that option.

Something like the following in your header:

```
<base href="~/" />
```

Otherwise, could you let us know where the following options are actually trying to look on the IIS server?

- Images/Background.png (no error)
- /Images/Background.png (404 error)
- ~/Images/Background.png (404 error)
- ~Images/Background.png(404 error)

Comment: Edited. I would prefer doing this in CSS though. Would i put the base tag in the head tags?

Comment: @brhardwick For the first image path listed, where it is looking at compared to where is the file at?  If it is looking in the same place as the file location, then it is unrelated to what I was thinking and seems to be a problem actually displaying the file.  If you use dev tools and watch the connection on the one with no error, is it actually finding the image?  If it has the image as a resource, then it is a dispaly problem.

Comment: The first one points to an actual file. Which is fairly disconcerting. When i look at the network tab, it doesnt even try to get the file. Or at least, it doesnt show that it tried to get it.